# Should we consider Deepfakes and fakenews as disinformation or misinformation?

Tags: terminology

Cognitive hacking some say is a new type of hacking field and some say it is something that been there for many years. Exploring the chapters of WIKI and using projects like [MisinfoSec](https://github.com/credcoalition/community-site/wiki/MisinfoSec-(The-Intersection-of-Misinformation-and-InfoSec)), got me confused about the differences between [disinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation) and [misinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misinformation) when it relates to [deepfakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepfake) and [fake news](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_news).

"Misinformation is misleading. Disinformation is a damn lie." that is the best one-liner [I found](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-misinformation-and-disinformation) explaining the difference. It is very confusing when I find these words used interchangeably while having a very different meaning when related to deepfakes and fakenews. Will you consider Deepfakes and fakenews as disinformation or misinformation hacks?

Comment: I did not downvote the question because of it's content or lack of research, but because it has basically no content. You show no research, no effort put into your question. I already put more effort into this question trying to understand what it actually is that you want to know than you put effort into making a good question. That's why I downvoted it.

Comment: Interesting topic, but it's not for this forum.

Comment: You are basically asking of manipulated information are just misleading or are they a lie. But this fully depends on how exactly and in which context it is used. Deepfakes or fake news can be mostly harmless misinformation but can also be used for disinformation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you are 100% right and this something that will be considered as a good answer, but as you see the wiki chapter and research papers making in most cases a strict usage of the words and classification

Comment: @Filipon: Please respect the opinions of others which find that your question is not a good fit for this site. Or do you consider yourself as much wiser than all the others or  you are the one who can decide how this site works?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich never thought I'm wiser than anyone here, especially with users that have as many points/score as you and others commented here.

Comment: @Filipon if there are no tags for the topic, there is a good chance that it is off-topic. There are technical and philosophical definitions for the terms that apply directly. And how they apply is determined by intent. As such, this is not a security question but a "theory of information" question.

Comment: @schroeder Good point! I think cognitive tag might be useful tag as we experience new related attack vectors and those that will come up in the near future.

Comment: @Filipon - please don't edit that tag back in. A mod removed it for a reason. We have guidelines as to when tags should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disinformation, in today's world, leads to misinformation.

Today, most media is owned by only 5 large corporations, so disinformation can be done extremely easy, especially for sensitive subjects like happenings in countries not aligned with the current globalized system. From there, it is widely and unintentionally spread everywhere.

So deep-fakes and fake news are created as disinformation, but end up as misinformation because any countering factor is quickly eliminated from public access and/or discredited, leading to having no viable way to counter what is happening.

This is a global tactic, but in an identical manner can be applied to isolated systems (like various countries, or any lower systems).